Poner una imagen sobre otra imagen con JLabels en Java(Sin usar netBeans)
buenas noches.
Estoy haciendo un ajedrez y he llegado a un problema que se a medias su respuesta, el problema es que para poner las piezas del ajedrez sobre el tablero tengo que superponer una imagen encima de otra.
La situacion es la siguiente, el area de juego es un JPanel, el teclado esta hecho a base de imagenes de las casillas cada una en un JLabel y las piezas irian en otro Jlabel que deberia ir superpuesto al de las casillas.
Lo que yo se es que en aplicaciones como NetBeans se puede poner a este Jpanel un AbsolutLayout y asi superponer esta clase de objetos pero al intentarlo en java aplicando (haciendo referencia al Jpanel) this.setLayout() no tengo forma de encontrar dentro el Absolut, hay algunos como flow o grid pero no son lo que yo busco.
Adjunto codigo de la clase en la que estoy haciendo el tablero (obviar la parte de run y el metodo paint)
`
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class TABLERO extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 900;
    //Las imagenes actuales al ser de 100 pixeles solo soportan tamaños inferiores a este
    private static final int TCASILLA = 100;
    private static int Xinicial=250;
    private static int Yinicial=25;
    public Icon icon;
    public JLabel imagen[][] =  new JLabel[8][8];

    final int FPS= 60;
    Thread HiloJuego;
    Controlador cr;
    public TABLERO() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.CreaTablero();
        cr =new Controlador();
        //pureba para meter la pieza de ajedrez
        JLabel imagen1= new JLabel();
        icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fotos/ReyB.png"));
        imagen1.setIcon(icon);
        imagen1.setBounds(250, 25, 40, 60);
        this.add(imagen1);
    }
    public void LanzarJuego() {
        HiloJuego =new Thread(this);
        HiloJuego.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double Intervalo= 1000000000/FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long ultiempo = System.nanoTime();
        long tiempoact; 
        while(HiloJuego != null) {
            tiempoact = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (tiempoact - ultiempo)/Intervalo;
            ultiempo= tiempoact;
            if(delta>= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        cr.update();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //g.fillRect(1200, HEIGHT/2, 99, 99);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        cr.pinta(g2);


    }
    private void CreaTablero() {
        int copia=Xinicial;
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++) {
                if(i%2==0) {
                    if(j%2==0) {
                        imagen[i][j]= new JLabel();
                        icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fotos/CasillaM.png"));
                        imagen[i][j].setIcon(icon);
                        imagen[i][j].setBounds(Xinicial, Yinicial, TCASILLA, TCASILLA);
                        this.add(imagen[i][j]);
                        Xinicial+=TCASILLA;
                    }
                    else {
                        imagen[i][j]= new JLabel();
                        icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fotos/CasillaB.png"));
                        imagen[i][j].setIcon(icon);
                        imagen[i][j].setBounds(Xinicial, Yinicial, TCASILLA, TCASILLA);
                        this.add(imagen[i][j]);
                        Xinicial+=TCASILLA;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(j%2==0) {
                        imagen[i][j]= new JLabel();
                        icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fotos/CasillaB.png"));
                        imagen[i][j].setIcon(icon);
                        imagen[i][j].setBounds(Xinicial, Yinicial, TCASILLA, TCASILLA);
                        this.add(imagen[i][j]);
                        Xinicial+=TCASILLA;
                    }
                    else {
                        imagen[i][j]= new JLabel();
                        icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fotos/CasillaM.png"));
                        imagen[i][j].setIcon(icon);
                        imagen[i][j].setBounds(Xinicial, Yinicial, TCASILLA, TCASILLA);
                        this.add(imagen[i][j]);
                        Xinicial+=TCASILLA;
                    }
                }
            }   
            Yinicial+=TCASILLA;
            Xinicial=copia;
        }
    }
    private void Coordenadas(int fila) {
        
    }
}

`
